# How do other government agency's get tags on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone know the process of requesting tags? Creating an Open Data beta site? Thank you!

Comment: on stack exchange, or on open data stack exchange (here)? this is a contentious question, as there is no set path for government agencies to do this, they just do. and then don't tell anyone here about it or come back here to support the tags.

Comment: There are two questions here (tags/site). Please limit to one because you will get completely different answers.

Comment: How do we get a tag on open data. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do we get a tag on open data

This is how I would do it.

1. Write a question
2. Tag the question

When you start writing a tag name, you will get auto-complete offering existing tags, but if you have something new, then when you press return a new tag will be created.

Please choose wisely, the use of the tag '[labor](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/labor/info)' to define *US Department of Labor developer portal, data and APIs* is an example of **what not to do**.  It prevents people asking questions about labor data (and tagging it as such) that doesn't apply to the US DoL...

3. Write some info about your new tag

Comment: no, do not create tags out of the blue. if there is a need for them, then create them. a need, as in multiple instances. do not create unique wildcards on the fly.